# Zip/Map Lists of Lists in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, zip

I have lists like:

```
L1 = [list]

L2 = [ [l1], [l2], ..., [ln] ]
```

I need to map these lists to

```
L = [ [list+l1] , [list + l2] , ..., [list + ln] ]
```

Right now I am just repeating L1 n times and then zipping them.  Can someone please hint me to a more elegant way?  In other words, I am looking to do this:

```
L=[]
L.append(L1 + L2[0])
L.append(L1 + L2[1])
...
```

It would also be nice if the solution would be robust to the following change:

```
L1 = [list1, list2, ..., listk]
```

and then L becomes

```
[ [list1 + list2 + ... + listk + l1] , ..., [list1 + list2 + ... + listk + ln] ]
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's rather unclear if `L1` is a normal list, or a list containing a single other list.  It would be nice if you could provide real code as examples to avoid such ambiguities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
L=[]
L.append(L1 + L2[0])
L.append(L1 + L2[1])
...
```

is equivalent to

```
L = [ L1+item for item in L2 ]
```

---

If `L1 = [list1, list2, ..., listk]` is a list of lists, such as

```
In [43]: L1 = [[1,2],[2,3]]
```

then `list1 + list2 + ... + listk` can be formed with `sum(L1, [])`:

```
In [44]: sum(L1,[])
Out[44]: [1, 2, 2, 3]

In [45]: [1,2]+[2,3]
Out[45]: [1, 2, 2, 3]
```

So in this case you could use

```
L1_sum = sum(L1, [])
L = [ L1_sum+item for item in L2 ]
```

(Aside: It is also possible to use `L = [ sum(L1, [])+item for item in L2 ]` but this would repeat the calculation of `sum(L1, [])` once for each item in `L2`.)

Comment: Thanks.  I will go with: L = [ list1 + list2 ... + listk +item for item in L2 ]

Answer (score 2):

Using list comprehensions is the pythonic way:

```
L = [ L1 + list for list in L2 ]
```